# SwiftUI change TextBox placeholder based on HttpResponse

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI and I am trying to implement a Forgot Password Functionality . The text field will say by default **Enter your email** then an http call takes places if the email is found in our system then I would like the Text PlaceHolder to Say **"Enter Verification Code"** . I already have everything else working . This is my code below. They enter their email then the HTTP call handles the rest and returns either a 0 or 1 in a closure depending on if the email is found . In the code below if the **foundEmail** is 1 then the Text placeholder should change to **Enter Verification Code**

```
struct ForgotPassWordView: View {
    @State private var textResponse = ""

    var body: some View {
        ZStack
            {
                Color.black
                VStack {
                    NavigationView {

                        Form {
                            Section {
                                TextField("Enter Email", text: $textResponse)
                               // change to Verification Code if foundEmail is 1
                            }

                            Section {

                                    HStack {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Button(action: {
                                            if !self.textResponse.isEmpty  {


                                                _ = ForgotPasswordRequest(email: self.textResponse, section: 1) {(foundEmail) in
                                                    if foundEmail == 0 {
                                                        //  not found do nothing
                                                    } else if foundEmail == 1
                                                    {
                                                        //  found email change to : Enter Verification Code
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                        }) {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Text("Submit").fontWeight(.bold).frame(width: 70.0)
                                            Spacer()
                                        }

                                        Spacer()
                                    }


                            }
                        }
                        .navigationBarTitle(Text(""))

                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15.0)

                    Text("Error Response").foregroundColor(.white)

                }
                .frame(height: 400.0)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: Best way is to use `combine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there I think you can use two TextField and switch views using a boolean because the placeHolder of text field not Binding so it cannot be edit... let me show what I mean in code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var verificationCode: String = ""
    @State var showCodeField: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    if (!showCodeField) {
                        TextField("Enter Valid Email", text: $email)
                    } else {
                        TextField("Enter Verification Code", text: $verificationCode)
                    }

                    Button(action: {
                        self.showCodeField.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Verify Email")
                    }
                }
                .padding()
            }
    }
}
```

also if you have a complex view you can extract them as variables and control which one is visible or not like this:

```
var someField: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).foregroundColor(Color.white)
      TextField("Enter Email", text: $email)
      }
    }
}
```

and in body you just call it like this

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
       if(isVisible) {
          someField
       }
}
```

[image: Email field showing]

[image: after clicking on the verify email button]